# Will there still be a separate Netbook edition after Unity becomes the default desktop environment?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook, desktop-environments

After a long time of enjoying the bliss of ignorance I've been reading up a bit on the developments in the land of desktop environments.
One thing I didn't find was whether there will still be (a need for) a separate netbook edition once Unity becomes the default environment on the Ubuntu desktop.
Surely someone here can tell me what I need to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging by [Gerry Carr's Canonical Blog post](http://blog.canonical.com/?p=528) as of Ubuntu 11.04 there will no longer be separate Ubuntu versions.

> One of the benefits of the direction
>   that’s been taken with the next
>   release of Ubuntu is that there is no
>   longer a need for a separate netbook
>   edition. The introduction of the new
>   shell for Ubuntu means that we have a
>   user interface that works equally well
>   whatever the form factor of the PC.
>   And the underlying technology works on
>   a range of architectures including
>   those common in netbook, notebooks,
>   desktops or whatever you choose to run
>   it on. Hence the need for a separate
>   version for netbooks is removed.

Even the name will simply be *Ubuntu* instead of *Ubuntu Desktop Edition* in the future.

Comment: That's all I needed to know. A merge between the Desktop and Netbook editions makes Ubuntu a whole lot more attractive to me–currently an Arch Linux user–and may mean I'll switch back to Ubuntu in the future. How the migration to GNOME 3 goes also hangs in that balance. Thank you for the quick response!